# Calculating of $\lim_{x\to 0^+} x^{(x^x-1)}$

Tags: calculus

When I  want calculate $\lim_{x\to 0^+} x^{(x^x-1)}$ , I have to calculate $\lim_{x\to 0^+}(x^x-1)\ln x$ . I calculat $\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^x=\lim_{x\to 0^+}e^{x\ln x}=1$ so $\lim_{x\to 0^+}(x^x-1)\ln x$ is $0\times \infty$ .

How can I calculate $\lim_{x\to 0^+}(x^x-1)\ln x$?

Comment: Can you compute $\lim_{x\to 0^+} (x^x-1)\ln x$?

Comment: Hint: $x^x=e^{x\log(x)}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use an asymptotic expansion of $\;x^x-1=\mathrm e^{x\ln x}-1=x\ln x+o(x\ln x)$. Thus,
$$(x^x-1)\ln x=x\ln^2x+o(x\ln x)\ln x=x\ln^2x+o(x\ln^2x)\xrightarrow[x\to 0^+]{}0$$
hence by continuity of the exponential function,
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} x^{x^x-1}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\mathrm e^{(x^x-1)\ln x}=\mathrm e^0=1.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \exp((x^x-1)\ln x) =$$

$$\exp(\lim_{x\to 0^+} (x^x-1)\ln x) = \exp(\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{x^x-1}{\frac1{\ln x}}) = \exp(\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\exp(x\ln x)-1}{\frac1{\ln x}})$$

Using Hopital

$$\exp(\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\exp(x\ln x)-1}{\frac1{\ln x}})=\exp(\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{(\ln x+1)\exp(x\ln x)}{\frac{-1}{x \ln^2 x}})=$$
$$=\exp(-\lim_{x\to 0^+} x \ln^2 x(\ln x+1)\exp(x\ln x))$$

Here we have $x \ln^3x$ and $x$ overcomes over $\ln^3 x$ the result is $\exp(0)=1$

Comment: $\exp(\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\exp(x\ln x)-1}{\frac1{\ln x}})=\exp(\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{(\ln x+1)\exp(x\ln x)}{\frac{-1}{x \ln^2 x}})$ is right But it is not important.

Comment: @Bimanifold thanks and fixed